# Google+ API - Check user account creation date

Tags: php, google-plus

Is it possible to check when an account was created with Google+ API?

I would like to allow account creation with Google+ only for Google+ users who have a Google+ account for more than one year.

Thank you.

Comment: That seems odd, what is the reason behind that design choice? Google+'s grown has increased substantially in the last year, wouldn't you lose a lot of prospective users?

Answer (score 2):

No, according to the [Google+ API documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people), the `People` resource doesn't have a property representing the creation date of the account.

I know this is also the case with the Facebook API. There must be a security reason for social networks not to make this information public, but I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: That's because it's critical information used for restoring your Google account in case it has been hacked. These used to be the required questions:

- What was the last password you used to sign-in to your Google Account?
- When was the last time you were able to sign in to your Google Account?- When did you create your Google Account?